How do I run an unload function in Chrome
I have found this about the deprecation of unload handlers:
https://github.com/fergald/docs/blob/master/explainers/permissions-policy-deprecate-unload.md
I've seen that using the visibilitychange event listener is a work around for this. My visibilitychange handler fires just fine when changing tabs or minimizing the window. However, when changing pages from, for example, localhost:5500 to google.com, I get the following error in my console.
[Violation] Permissions policy violation: unload is not allowed in this document.
Here is my code snippet below that I am testing this out with:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", () => {
        if (document.visibilityState === "hidden") {
          console.log("visibility >>>>");
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

Am I just truly out of luck with getting an unload handler working of any sort? I'm trying to send analytics data when the user leaves the page

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon
